# Weird behaviour of a counter in process() method of Javacard

Tags: javacard

I use a `static short` field named `counter` in the `process()` method of my Java Card applet to count the number of this method firings!

Well, the program is really simple and looks like this:

```
package testPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class Test extends Applet {

    public static short counter = 0x0000;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new Test().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }
        counter = (short) (counter + 1);
        ISOException.throwIt(counter);

    }
}
```

When I install this applet in the regular way, it works fine:

**Regular Installing:**

```
GlobalPlatformPro:> gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)


GlobalPlatformPro:> gp -install d:\test.cap

GlobalPlatformPro:> gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,

AID: 010203040501020304 (|.........|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

AID: 010203040501 (|......|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     010203040501020304 (|.........|)
```

**Regular installing, applet output:**

```
OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s 00A4040009010203040501020304 -s 00000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 09 01 02 03 04 05 01 02 03 04
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x01)

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s 00A4040009010203040501020304 -s 00000000 -s 0000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 09 01 02 03 04 05 01 02 03 04
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x02)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x03)
```

But when I install it as `default selected` applet, the counter works different:

**installing as Default selected applet:**

```
GlobalPlatformPro:> gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)


GlobalPlatformPro:> gp -install d:\test.cap -default

GlobalPlatformPro:> gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, CVM (PIN) managem

AID: 010203040501020304 (|.........|)
     App SELECTABLE: Default selected

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

AID: 010203040501 (|......|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     010203040501020304 (|.........|)
```

**Default selected, applet output:**

```
OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s 00A4040009010203040501020304 -s 00000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 09 01 02 03 04 05 01 02 03 04
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x06)

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s 00A4040009010203040501020304 -s 00000000 -s 0000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 09 01 02 03 04 05 01 02 03 04
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x0C)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x0D)
```

As you see above, when I installed the applet as `Default Selected`, the counters increases by **6** with each command (instead of increasing by 1)!

What is happening on the background?

---

**Update 1:**

Based on dear @Vojta's comment, I changed the program in way to increase the `counter` value for APDU commands with `CLA = 0x80` only:

```
public void process(APDU apdu) {
    if (selectingApplet()) {
        return;
    }

    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

    if ((buffer[ISO7816.CLA_ISO7816] & 0x00FF) == 0x80 ) {
        counter = (short) (counter + 1);
    }

    ISOException.throwIt(counter);

}
```

This is the output (for **Default selected case**):

```
OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s 00A4040009010203040501020304 -s 00000000 -s 8000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 09 01 02 03 04 05 01 02 03 04
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 80 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x01)

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s 00A4040009010203040501020304 -s 00000000 -s 80000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 09 01 02 03 04 05 01 02 03 04
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x01)
Sending: 80 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x02)

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s 00A4040009010203040501020304 -s 00000000 -s 8000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 09 01 02 03 04 05 01 02 03 04
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x02)
Sending: 80 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x03)
```

Comment: It seems to me it increases by 5 with each select, not with each command (`0x0C` -> `0x0D`)... However, it does not explain anything.

Comment: Something must send you some extra APDUs, probably with CLA=0x00... Could you please increase the counter for CLA=0x80 only and test it again?

Comment: do you have a PKCS11 module activated in some browser or email program?

Comment: and can you display all APDUs send by your tools instgead of the command line

Comment: @vojta You are right. The counter increases only for `SELECT` APDU command. I increased the counter for `CLA=0x80` and it worked as we expected. Question updated.

Comment: @PaulBastian : _"do you have a PKCS11 ..."_ Hmmm! I don't think so.

Comment: @PaulBastian _"can you display all APDUs send ..."_ Well, I think this is all! Do you mean verbose mode, or debug mode? If so, I think my tool doesn't have this capability!

Comment: Some Tool is sending commands to the card and the applet reacts because it is default selected

Comment: if you dont have any program using a smartcard it might be Windows CardSpace if you work under Windows? I had a similar problem some years ago...  edit: try disabling Windows CardSpace in the services.msc

Comment: @PaulBastian I think it is not CardSpace as such, it is particularly scPnP. I encountered the very similar issue a few years ago. Windows 7 has introduced a new feature: plug&play for smart cards. Abraham: Windows 7 tries to communicate with your card (to find out what card it is), but your applet is default selected and so it handles all the APDUs sent by Windows. Please, try to edit your registry entries using regedit as described here http://www.ugochirico.com/post/2010/10/22/Disable-the-Smart-Card-Plug-Play-Option-in-Windows-7.aspx and test it again, please.

Comment: yeah might be that, its quite some time ago so I don't remember all the details but he should be on the right track now

Comment: @PaulBastian Dear Paul,I checked _CardSpace_ in the _services.exe_, well,it is disabled in my computer by default.

Comment: @vojta Dear Vojta, I couldn't find that path in my registry, so I used [this manual](https://www.charismathics.com/fileadmin/files/pdf/manuals/How_to_disable_smart_card_plug_and_play.pdf) instead and I disabled the SCPnP service via `gpedit.msc`, but nothing changed